# Bison shift/reduce conflict, cannot remove ambiguity from parser

Tags: c++, bison

When I run my bison code in Linux Mint I get these warnings:

```
warning: 64 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
```

I cannot find the ambiguity. I've tried to make my implementation hanlde both INT and FLOAT datatypes, but I believe that is the source of the warnings.

My Bison code is below:

```
%{
   /**
    * Definition section
    */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    /**
     * Declare stuff from Flex that Bison needs to know about:
     */
     
    extern int yylex();
    extern int yyparse();
    extern FILE* yyin;
    extern int line_num;

    void yyerror(const char* s);
%}

/** Bison fundamentally works by asking flex to get the next token,
 * which it returns as an object of type "yystype". Initially (by default),
 * yystype is merely a typedef of "int", but for non-trivial projects, tokens
 * could be of any arbitrary data type. So, to deal with that, the idea is to 
 * override yystype's default typedef to a C union instead. Unions can hold all
 * of the types of tokens that Flex could return, and this means we can return
 * ints or floats or string cleanly. Bison implements this mechanism with the
 * %union directive:
 */
%union {
    int ival;
    float fval;
}

/**
 * Define the "Terminal Symbol" toke types. We use (in CAPS by convention),
 * and associate each with a field of the %union:
 */
%token<ival> INT
%token<fval> FLOAT
%token PLUS MINUS MULTIPLY DIVIDE
%token NEWLINE QUIT

%type<ival> expression
%type<fval> mixed_expression

%start calculation

%%

calculation:
           | calculation line
;

line: NEWLINE
    | mixed_expression NEWLINE {printf("\tResult: %f\n", $1);}
    | expression NEWLINE {printf("\tResult: %i\n", $1);}
    | QUIT NEWLINE {printf("bye!\n"); exit(0);}
;

mixed_expression: FLOAT                             {$$ = $1;}
    | mixed_expression PLUS mixed_expression        {$$ = $1 + $3;}
    | mixed_expression MINUS mixed_expression       {$$ = $1 - $3;}
    | mixed_expression MULTIPLY mixed_expression    {$$ = $1 * $3;}
    | mixed_expression DIVIDE mixed_expression      {$$ = $1 / $3;}
    | expression PLUS mixed_expression              {$$ = $1 + $3;}
    | expression MINUS mixed_expression             {$$ = $1 - $3;}
    | expression MULTIPLY mixed_expression          {$$ = $1 * $3;}
    | expression DIVIDE mixed_expression            {$$ = $1 / $3;}
    | mixed_expression PLUS expression              {$$ = $1 + $3;}
    | mixed_expression MINUS expression             {$$ = $1 - $3;}
    | mixed_expression MULTIPLY expression          {$$ = $1 * $3;}
    | mixed_expression DIVIDE expression            {$$ = $1 / $3;}
    | expression DIVIDE expression                  {$$ = $1 / (float)$3;}
;

expression: INT                                     {$$ = $1;}
          | expression PLUS expression              {$$ = $1 + $3;}
          | expression MINUS expression             {$$ = $1 - $3;}
          | expression MULTIPLY expression          {$$ = $1 * $3;}
;

%%

int main(int, char**) {
    // Open a file handle to a particular file:
    FILE *myfile = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    // Make sure it is valid:
    if(!myfile) {
        cout << "I can't open numbers.txt!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // Set Flex to read from it instead of defaulting to STDIN:
    yyin = myfile;

    // Parse through the input:
    yyparse();
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    cout << "AAAHHHH, parse error on line " << line_num << "! Message: " << s << endl;
    // might as well halt now:
    exit(-1);
}
```

I believe that the issue may be with my implementation of **expression** and **mixed_expression**.

Answer (score 0):

The datatype of a computation is semantic, not syntactic; intuitively, one wouldn't expect a grammar to deal with it. Under some very limited circumstances it's possible — your attempt is workable, at least until you decide to implement variables — but it's almost never a good idea.

But that's not what's producing the shift-reduce conflicts. The problem is that your grammar is ambiguous and you have not told Bison how to resolve the ambiguities. The grammar is ambiguous because `4-2*3` could be parsed either as `expression(4-2) TIMES expression(3)` or as `expression(4) MINUS expression(2*3)`, which obviously have different values. The usual way to resolve this particular ambiguity is through [precedence declarations](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Precedence), which you will find deployed in pretty well all of the useful [example parsers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Infix-Calc).

Comment: Another way (besides explicit %precedence declarations) is to separate out various expression types and build lower-precedence expressions out of higher. i.e.: primary_expression: VALUE | '(' expression ')' ; muldiv_expression: primary_expression | muldiv_expression '*' primary_expression | muldiv_expression '/' primary_expression ; addsub_expression: muldiv_expression | addsub_expression '+' muldiv_expression | addsub_expression '-' muldiv_expression ; and so on through all your precedence levels. I'm honestly not sure whether there is any benefit to one style over the other.

Comment: @soronel: the precedence version is slightly shorter, somewhat faster (fewer unit reductions) and a bit easier to read. On the other hand, it relies on actually understanding how precedence works, and can mask grammar bugs.